# Como seleccionar el campo con la fecha mas reciente con distinto ID

Tags: mysql

Tengo la siguiente tabla en la cual tengo una misma persona con distinto ID y solo deseo mostrar al que tenga la fecha mas reciente.

| ID | Fecha | Estado | Nombre |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 05-DEC-20 | Cancelada | Juanito |
| B | 01-DEC-20 | Cancelada | Juanito |

Intente con lo siguiente pero no resulto

```
SELECT ID, MAX(FECHA) AS FECHA, ESTADO
FROM TABLA 
GROUP BY ID, FECHA, ESTADO
```

También con lo siguiente pero ahora no muestra nada

```
SELECT ID, FECHA, ESTADO
FROM TABLA 
WHERE FECHA = (SELECT MAX(FECHA)FROM TABLA)
```

Comment: @BetaM Si lo hice sin agrupar el campo FECHA pero tampoco resulta

Comment: @BetaM Me muestra ambos campos cuando solo quiero uno el con fecha mas reciente

Comment: Si agregas `limit 1`?

Comment: Por qué la misma persona tiene `id` diferentes? Si hay otra persona con ese mismo nombre cómo los diferencias?

Comment: @Bicho esto involucra mas campos solo puse un ejemplo ya que son montones y hay algunas que incluso son 4 repetidos con distinto id y mismo nombre(nombre, rut) y diferente fecha

Answer (score 0):

Creo que tu fecha podría ser varchar y por eso no funciona tu segunda opcion.

```
SELECT ID, FECHA, ESTADO FROM TABLA WHERE FECHA = (SELECT MAX(TO_DATE(FECHA,'DD-MMM-YY') FROM TABLA)
```

puedes intentar así? si es el caso debería funcionar

Comment: La función `TO_DATE` no existe en MySQL, creo que deberías usar [**`STR_TO_DATE`**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

Comment: Ya, no me fije que estaba en mysql específicamente, revisa https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-str_to_date/

Comment: Precisamente por eso te hice el comentario y te dejé el enlace de la doc. oficial :) para que puedas editar y corregir ese aspecto

Comment: Gracias, la corrección la dejo a cargo del author del thread. Independientemente de la implementación o la base de datos que utilice, no es lo mismo hacer un MAX('varchar') a una fecha, number, u otros data types.

Comment: hola, intente transformando a DATE, pero ahora no me muestra ninguno de los 2 campos, el tipo de dato de la fecha es un INTEGER

Comment: Integer? puedes compartir el DDL de tu tabla?